# How can I recreate the synthesizer at the end of C418's Équinoxe?

Tags: sound-design

I can't seem to wrap my head around on how to filter this thing.

(If the embed doesn't work here is the link)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13-P3nJGq7TSTqDalsL3kK2HdabDBNz0T/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Which synth?  I hear at least 4 there.